# Shut down Thread in Jmeter take so much time

Tags: jmeter, blazemeter

[image]

This was Ultimate Thread Group in Jmeter.
I used Blazemeter extension to create .jmx file then replace with ultimate thread group

Although i put 30 second shut down time.

When it reach the maximum thread and Hold Load was finished it seem doesnt shut down thread (Very slow 1 or 2 thread every 20 seconds). Is there anything that i could do to solve this problems?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most probably your application gets overloaded and starts responding slowly.

JMeter politely "asks" threads to stop when they will be free and threads in their turn kindly wait for the system under test to respond (in order to avoid potential [Socket Closed](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/jmeter/JMeterSocketClosed) errors). Once it responds they're immediately stopped.

So the solution is to set reasonable timeouts using i.e. [HTTP Request Defaults](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-http-request)

[image]

as JMeter doesn't have any pre-defined timeout and if server won't respond or cut the connection from its end - JMeter will wait for the response forever.

Also consider [removing Listeners from your test plan](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#lean_mean), they don't add any value and just consume resources